# Overlay java maps, adding all keys

Tags: java, dictionary

Does anyone know if there's a map structure or library that easily supports adding up the values of a map when combining two maps.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> score1 = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String, Integer> addition = new HashMap<>();

score1.put("Chicaco", 2);
score1.put("New york", 1);

addition.put("New york", 1);
addition.put("Los Angeles", 1);
```

Is there some way to combine score1 with addition so that the result is a map with
    "Chicago" -> 2,
    "New york" -> 2,
    "Los Angeles" -> 1?

I know I could iterate using streams and the new (Java 8) compute() on Map, but is there any other way which does not require manual iteration?

I'm thinking there must be some better way than handling the iteration by yourself such as in:

```
addition.forEach((k1, v1) -> score1.compute(k1, (k2, v2) -> v2==null?v1:v1+v2));
score1.forEach((k,v)-> System.out.println(k+":"+v));
```

Comment: Sashi is closest, but almost everyone failes to see that New York must be updated to the sum of values for New York in each map. That is -> 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for alternative of

```
addition.forEach((k1, v1) -> score1.compute(k1, (k2, v2) -> v2==null?v1:v1+v2));
```

then

```
addition.forEach((k, v) -> score1.merge(k, v, (v1, v2) -> v1 + v2));
```

seems like improvement.

So your code can also look like:

```
Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
score1.forEach((k, v) -> result.merge(k, v, (v1, v2) -> v1 + v2));
addition.forEach((k, v) -> result.merge(k, v, (v1, v2) -> v1 + v2));
```

You can also rewrite it using streams, like:

```
Map<String, Integer> map2 = Stream.concat(
        score1.entrySet().stream(),
        addition.entrySet().stream()
).collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Entry::getKey, 
        Entry::getValue, 
        (v1, v2) -> v1+ v1)
);
```

but I find `forEach` solution cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Grouping the stream of `Entry<String, Integer>`:

```
    Map<String, Integer> r = Stream.of(score1, addition)
        .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(),
             Collectors.summingInt(e -> e.getValue())));
```

Comment: This solution removes Los Angeles

Comment: @Billybong No the result is `{Chicaco=2, New york=2, Los Angeles=1}`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try below....

```
score1.putAll(addition);
```

This will add all values of addition to score1.

Comment: No, it wouldn't add value to an existing item. So result would be: "Chicago" -> 2,
"New york" -> 1,
"Los Angeles" -> 1

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use Guava [Multiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html).

```
Multiset<String> score1 = HashMultiset.create();
Multiset<String> addition = HashMultiset.create();

score1.add("Chicaco", 2);
score1.add("New york", 1);

addition.add("New york", 1);
addition.add("Los Angeles", 1);
```

then you can combine them:

```
Multiset<String> sum = Multisets.sum(score1, addition);
```